# port 8888 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following issue trying to call a web service listening port 8888:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/rauco/oxygen/1/1/last net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED functions.misc.js:43
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input functions.misc.js:46
```

function.misc.js:

```
function get_last_oxygen(location, start_time, end_time)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    var oxy_url = 'http://localhost:8888/' + location + '/oxygen/1/1/last';
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", oxy_url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );// line 43
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);//line 46
            var oxy = document.getElementById('oxygen');
            oxy.innerHTML = json.oxygen;
            get_oxygen_range(location, start_time, end_time);
            //alert(xmlHttp.status + ' ' + xmlHttp.responseText);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That means there's no server running on port 8888, or maybe the firewall is blocking it.

Comment: there is not firewall, the web service works fine if I put http://localhost:8888/rauco/oxygen/1/1/last on the navigator.

Comment: sorry I was not running de web service. Now I get XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/rauco/oxygen/1/1/last. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: To prevent the error on line 46, you should check `if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)`.

Comment: Using a different port in the AJAX request than the original page violates the AJAX Same-Origin policy.

Comment: so what can I do to walk through the issue?

Comment: Search SO for other questions with that error message, you'll find explanations and possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it works from a browser, then try changing the url from localhost to 127.0.0.1 . If it works, then it means your environment is not resolving localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: This is a most unlikely solution, as many things are likely to break if `localhost` doesn't resolve correctly.

Comment: Also, if it works from the browser, that means that `localhost` is resolving correctly -- the browser address bar uses the same resolver as Javascript does.

Comment: I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and I got the same.

Comment: Is your server getting killed while it is serving the request. I know this would have been obvious to you, bt asking jst in case u didnt notice